# Logic in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have need of some logic in a stored procedure. All the stored procedure does it perform a couple of logic rules and then returns a true or false depending on the result.

The pseudo SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE #PV ([Date] DATETIME, Dis FLOAT, Del Float, Sold Float)
INSERT #PV exec GetPVSummaryReport @ID, @PID, @From, @To
SELECT AVG(Dis) / 8 AS DisAvg, AVG(Del) AS DelAvg FROM #PV
IF DisAvg > 20 -- this is the bit I am having problems grokking
    RETURN TRUE
ELSE
    -- do longer calculation
```

**How do you do this sort of logic?**

Notes about the code: The table #PV has 4 fields - those provided (Date, Dis, Del and Sold).

Comment: Does it have to be a stored procedure?  This seems like it may be easier and more useful in application code.

Comment: Since I need to hit the database twice to find a boolean value, it seemed better to use an SP so I don't perform excessive network chatter.  Also it will be called about 20 times in quick succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @DisAvg float
declare @DelAvg float

-- Instantiate #PV etc

select
  @DisAvg = avg(Dis) / 8,
  @DelAvg = avg(Del)
from
  #PV

if @DisAvg > 20
  return
else
  -- Do something else
```

Comment: The RETURN statement should have a value to indicate the condition the procedure was in upon termination.

Comment: The question applied to expressions, not return values. I deliberately chose not to return anything in particular.

Comment: Fair enough.  +1 for simplest solution that seems to be basically what graham is looking for.

Comment: Since Luke was the first, and his code did demonstrate where I was going wrong, he get's the tick.

Answer (score 2):

why is everyone creating a Temp Table? Variable tables are so much nicer ([and more performant](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx)) :)

lets see...

```
DECLARE @PV TABLE ([Date] DATETIME,
    Dis FLOAT,
    Del FLOAT,
    Sold FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @PV
EXEC [dbo].[GetPVSummaryReport] @ID, @PID, @From, @To


-- Create some variables, which will contain the results.
DECLARE @DisAvg AS FLOAT,
    @DelAvg AS FLOAT

-- Retrieve results into a variables.
SELECT @DisAvg = AVG(Dis) / 8, @DelAvg AVG(Del)
FROM @PV

-- Check results...    
IF @DisAvg > 20 
   RETURN TRUE
ELSE BEGIN
    -- do longer calculation
END

-- NOTE: I'm not sure where you use @DelAvg .. 
--       I'm assuming it's in the 'do longer calculation' section.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Did you actually read the article you linked to? In certain conditions table variables perform far worse than temporary tables.

Comment: According to this (http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html) you can't use a table variable if you "INSERT @table EXEC sp_someProcedure" which is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: The @DelAvg was supposed to be in the OR section of the logic.  I removed it when trying to determine how to work with SQL.

Comment: @Luke : Yep, I have ages back. In certain conditions? please. In certain conditions, i'll fall out of bed and an asteroid will hit the earth. There's _always_ a `certain condition`. What about the `common/general condition`? I'm under the impression that, generally, it (variable tables) perform better that the old school temp tables.

Comment: @Graham.Reeds: Sure about that Graham? i'm doing `INSERT INTO @table` all the time. (/me runs off, tests this out .. runs back). Confirmed. It _does_ work. Please try it yourself. takes one sec.

Answer (score 1):

**LABELS** are a beautiful things. **LABELS** allow you to use **GOTO's** and this lets you write simple to follow logic inside your stored procedures.

```
DECLARE @Result int
SET @Result = 1 -- 1=True 0=False

IF TEST1 Failed
BEGIN
  SET @Result = 0
  GOTO ENDPROCESSING
END

IF TEST2 Failed
BEGIN
  SET @Result = 0
  GOTO ENDPROCESSING
END
IF TEST3 Failed
BEGIN
  SET @Result = 0
  GOTO ENDPROCESSING
END

ENDPROCESSING:
SELECT @Result
```

Comment: Neat. Never knew SP had goto.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable and select into it

```
DECLARE @DisAvg DOUBLE, @DelAvg DOUBLE
SELECT @DisAvg = AVG(Dis) / 8, @DelAvg = AVG(Del) #PV
IF @DisAvg > 20 -- this is the bit I am having problems grokking
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    -- do longer calculation
```

Declare with the correct type of the Dis field.

**Edit** - corrected the return value.

Comment: return can return only integers

Comment: Dude. fail. RETURN can return FLOATS, BIT, etc... Sif only INTEGERS. tsk tsk!

Comment: Yep, you're right. I corrected the code example. I just copied the pseudo-code and missed that.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @DisAvg DECIMAL
DECLARE @ReturnValue bit
```

// use SET or SELECT to assign values to @DisAvg

```
IF (@DisAvg > 20)
BEGIN 
    SET  @ReturnValue = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    -- do longer calculation
SET @ReturnValue = 0
END 
SELECT @ReturnValue
```

Only integers can be returned from the `RETURN` statement, you can use `SELECT` instead

Comment: You are not populating @DisAvg with the average - you are taking the last Dis entry from #PV