# Variables and stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572012/logic-in-stored-procedure/1572021#1572021) I would like to know if there is a simple way of doing the following (which doesn't compile):

```
CREATE TABLE #PV ([ID] INT, [Date] DATETIME, Dis FLOAT, Del Float, Sold Float)
INSERT #PV @ID, exec GetPVSummaryReport @ID, @PID, @From, @To
```

The reason is I need to join #PV onto another table by [ID], but the original stored procedure doesn't have the necessary parameter.

Updating the SP is difficult (not impossible) as the code is 'out-in-the-wild' and I'd prefer not to have 'GetPVSummaryReport2' (which we already have several of already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #PV ([Date] DATETIME, Dis FLOAT, Del Float, Sold Float)
INSERT #PV EXECUTE GetPVSummaryReport @ID, @PID, @From, @To
SELECT @ID as [ID], * FROM #PV
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE #PV ([ID] INT NULL, [Date] DATETIME, Dis FLOAT, Del Float, Sold Float)
INSERT #PV ([Date], Dis, Del, Sold) EXECUTE GetPVSummaryReport @ID, @PID, @From, @To
UPDATE #PV SET [ID] = @ID
SELECT * FROM #PV
```

Comment: I was so focused on getting the table into via insert I didn't consider the use of update!